# How to get coverage report for external APIs?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm trying to get coverage report for the API code. I have all the test cases running perfectly in mocha. My problem is that my API server and the test cases are written in separate repositories.

I start my node API server on localhost, on a particular port, and then using supertest in mocha, hit the localhost url to test server's response.

Can you suggest me the best way to generate a coverage report for those APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Testing env

If you want to get coverage, supertest should be able to bootstrap the app server, like in the [express example](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest#example).

The drawback is that *you must not run your tests against a running server*, like

```
var api = request('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
```

but you must include your app entrypoint to allow supertest to start it like

```
var app = require('../yourapp'); 
var api = request(app);
```

Of course, this may (or may not) result in a bit of refactoring on your app bootstrap process.

As other options, you can use node CLI debug capabilities or use [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector).

### Coverage setup

Supposing you are willing to install [istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) in association with mocha to get coverage.

```
npm install -g istanbul
```

then

```
istanbul cover mocha --root <path> -- --recursive <test-path>
```

- `cover` is the command use to generate code coverage
- `mocha` is the executable js file used to run tests
- `--root <path>` the root path to look for files to instrument (aka the "source files")
- `--` is used to pass arguments to your test runner
- `--recursive <test-path>` the root path to look for test files

You can then add `--include-all-sources` to get cover info on all your source files.

In addition you can get more help running
`istanbul help cover`

Comment: `--root <path>` should point to the path of my test cases, or my route handlers?

Comment: It should point to the source code of the app (aka the code to be instrumented).

Comment: When I run this command `istanbul cover mocha --root /path/to/other/repo/`, none of my test cases run, as I see `0 passing` message from mocha. Where should I provide path for my test cases?

Comment: mocha by default run files under `test/`. If you used another directory you can pass it as an argument like
`istanbul cover mocha --root /path/to/other/repo/ -- --recursive /path/to/tests`. Beware the double dashes before recursive!

Comment: Sorry for late reply. So I ran this command now `istanbul cover mocha --root /path/to/other/repo/ -- --recursive /path/to/tests/`, and my tests run correctly, but at the end I see this: `No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information`. **PS** I run this command in the test cases repo, and my API code is in some other repo outside the test cases repo, so probably, istanbul doesn't know what lines of codes are being executed for the APIs, and therefore no coverage for them.

Comment: Yes, the command is ok. Did you meet the requirements of the first part (testing env)? Your should not run your tests against your running server (for e.g. like `var api = request('http://127.0.0.1:3000');`), instead your should require your app (e.g. like `var app = require('../yourapp');
var api = request(app);`). Of course, this may (or may not) result in a bit of refactoring on your part.

Comment: Is there any way to run your tests against a running server with nyc? My app runs in a Docker container before the tests run and it would be a pain to refactor.

Comment: It would if you only care to run tests... if you need coverage you need to instrument your source code.